# why react component iterated but overlapping DOM

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Child Component using WebSocket to get data from server
this working fine,

output of the code is correct when passing string
[image: code output]

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { WebsocketContext } from "./Wsconnection";
import React from "react";

const Allotments = ({ num }) => {
  const [isReady, socket] = useContext(WebsocketContext);
  const [allotdata, setAllotdata] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isReady) {
      socket.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "get_allotment_details", number: num }));
      socket.onmessage = (e) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        if (data.type === "get_allotment_details") {
          const altdata = data.alloted_details[0];
          setAllotdata({ customer: altdata.prq__customer__name });
        }
      };
    }
    return () => {};
  }, [isReady, num, socket]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h5>{allotdata?.customer}</h5>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Allotments;
```

Parent Component

```
import React from "react";
import Allotments from "./Allotments";

const init_alloted = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("reporting").dataset.alloted) || [];

export const Alloted = () => {
  const allots = init_alloted.map((allot, idx) => {
    return (
      <div key={idx}>
        <Allotments num={allot.number} key={idx} />
      </div>
    );
  });

  return <div className="col">{allots}</div>;
};
```

i tried passing text string then, everything works fine

Comment: what behavior do you want? you want them to be appended like a list ?

Comment: yes like a normal list item

Comment: then why don't you call the `websocket` in parent component and append to the list...then use the list to `map` the child components

Comment: Because i have many fields from websocket of single allotment, but i can work around to apply this